# Hide dynamic layout on certain routes in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I set dynamic layout in the following way:

`LayoutDefault.vue`

```
<template>
 <div class="LayoutDefault">
    <nav>
     .
     . 
     .

   </nav>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

`LayoutDefaultDynamic.js`

```
import LayoutDefault from './LayoutDefault.vue'

export default {
  name: 'LayoutDefaultDynamic',
  created() {
    this.$parent.$emit('update:layout', LayoutDefault);
  },
  render() {
    return this.$slots.default[0];
  },
};
```

Now in some components I use this layout:

```
<template>
  <!--  Use layout-defualt component for rendering certain layout in this page-->
  <layout-default-dynamic>
      <v-container fluid class="grid-container">
  .
  .
  .
</layout-default-dynamic>
```

But there are components that I dont use any layout.
This is how I set up `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <component :is="layout">
      <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
          <router-view :layout.sync="layout" />
      </transition>
    </component>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      layout: "div",
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

The problem is that when I go to routes(pages) that are not wrapped in `<layout-default-dynamic>` I still can see that layout on them. Is there a way to exclude those routes to have this layout displayed on them?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use nested routes in Vue router. You create two layout and add them as top level routes and add children routes to them. I've created sample app to show my case.

In my sample I've created `AdminLayout.vue` and `DefaultLayout.vue` like the following:

```
//admin layout.
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Admin Layout</h1>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "admin-layout"
};
</script>

//default layout.
<template>
  <div>
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
    <h1>Default Layout</h1>
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>|
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>|
      <router-link to="/admin/user">User</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "default-layout"
};
</script>
```

Note that each layout has its own `<router-view></router-view>`.

In the route file I defined my routes like:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "default",
    component: DefaultLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/home",
        name: "home",
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        name: "About",
        component: About
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/admin",
    name: "admin",
    component: AdminLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: "user",
        name: "name",
        component: User
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Now any nested routes in `/admin` will use the `AdminLayout` and same for the `/` route. You can check the sample:

[image: Edit intelligent-sid-k6ehr]

Comment: This is fine approach, I've used it before in different project, however I found out it is possible to this dynamic kind of import, I just need to figure out how to exclude one of the views from this layout.

Comment: @AlexT Could you create a small sample and add it to the question?